# Fastest way to transfer a bunch of photos TO iphone camera roll?

Tags: iphone, camera, file-transfer

what is the quickest way to transfer a bunch of photos (and videos) that come from an iphone to another iPhone's camera roll?

- Sync with iPhoto/Aperture is not an option: they wouldn't end up in the camera roll
- Opening from email or dropbox one by one and saving them is not an option: too many!
- A big email is not feasible

AirSharing and Dropbox apps are apparently of little help, since I couldn't find a “save all” command.

Any suggestion is welcome, third party apps too!

Comment: The question includes a false predicate. There's a way (albeit not an obvious one) to "select all" images in camera roll.

Comment: @DanielK. I'm pretty sure there was not a way to "select all" back in 2010 when I asked the question :)

Comment: you are right. I don't know when this "feature" (i.e. scroll to top) was added. You now might want to accept a different answer as "best answer"   if this is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Phoneview -](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/.) is a great option.  It's fast too.  Connect iphone, copy the files to your desired directory, disconnect.  Connect other iphone, copy files to desired location on iphone.  Boom!

Drag n drop ease.  Free download, and cheap too. **edit:** it allows you to see entire disk media folder :)

[image]

Comment: LOL! I already had a license for PhoneView, but didn't know this feature! I'll add the details to complete the procedure, for future reference. Open PhoneView, enable entire disk (preferences), put all the photos in one of the APPLE100, or APPLE101 subdirectories of the DCIM directory, then go into PhotoData and delete /PhotoData/Photos.sqlite and /PhotoData/PhotosAux.sqlite. Last step, close and reopen the Images app, and the iPhone will rebuild the database. Sweet, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use " PicBack - Photo Transfer App " it works with a regular USB cable, which is 3x faster than WiFi transfer and there is absolutely no third-party software to install
it imports photos and videos directly To camera roll and it can also find duplicated photos , very handy and very easy to use, you can find it at the app store

"https://itun.es/i6BG5cC"

Give that a try ;)

Comment: Isn't  PicBack a third party app?

Answer (score 2):

The app GoodReader can save videos to Camera Roll. Simply transfer files to GoodReader via iTunes, then in GoodReader select "Manage Files" -> "Export" -> "Save to Photots".

Answer (score 0):

there is another free way to transfer one photo or many photos from iPhone to computer. That is, you can use Apple's Wifi Photo Transfer to do it. The only disadvantage is that your iPhone and computer should on the same Wifi networks.

Comment: Can you explain in detail how this would work?

Answer (score 0):

One way to transfer photos to your camera roll:
Send the photo via email to yourself.
When you open the email on your iphone tap the photo once; camera roll message appears you tap on the camera roll icon and voila! it's transferred to camera roll.

Answer (score 0):

Check out an app called [Folder Plus](http://theverygames.com/folder-plus/).

Very minimalist design, easy to understand and packed full of useful functionality. Seriously it is one of the best apps when it comes to working with files on your phone. Photos, music, videos, and even incompatible files can be stored and/or passed through the app to their destination. I think there is a free version and a paid version on the Apple App Store.

And there is a free OS X companion app that really makes quick work of any files you want to move onto or from your phone called [Folder Plus USB](http://theverygames.com/folder-plus-usb/). It requires Mavericks or later to run on your Mac.

For the record: I have no affiliation with the maker of this app in any way. It really is just a great little program that has gone under the radar for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

## Use AirDrop!

There's an (admittedly non-obvious) way to "select all" images in camera roll.

Follow the description given here: https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/use-trick-quickly-select-all-photos-videos-your-iphone-bulk-delete-share-0312925/

Basically select at least the two newest images by sliding over them with a finger. Then without lifting this finger, use another finger to tap the top of the screen. The screen will immediately jump-scroll to the oldest picture and all pictures will have been selected by this process.

Now you can AirDrop them as usual.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [**Rollit**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rollit-photo-transfer-app/id741790426?mt=8) to import your photos and videos into to the camera roll.

Answer (score -2):

Bump https://bu.mp/ can do this.
Also try PhotoSync.

Comment: *Bump is no longer available.*