# Can I transfer or sync purchased as well as non-purchased songs from my iPhone to my computer?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, data-transfer

So, I wiped my drive clean on my MacBook and reinstalled the OS. Happily the best of my music was safe on my iPhone and I figured it would easily flow back to my iTunes library.

Not so happily, I can't seem to figure out how to get this music, which is mine, to the laptop, which is mine, from the iphone, which is mine.

I don't want to jailbreak my phone just for this one task, I'm running iOS 4.2.1 on an iPhone 3G and my MacBook 5,1 runs OS X version 10.6.5.

I would like my music back.  How to do this?

Comment: I gave the correct answer to senuti, but upvoted both.  Using these tools, I remember what it was like to actually use my devices to their capabilities.  Thanks!

Comment: This helped me recover the music on my phone after having my house broken into and my laptop stolen. Thanks for making a really crappy day a little bit better.

Comment: Thank the people who answered.  Shitty to hear about your laptop.  :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Things you've purchased off the iTunes Store can be transferred off your iPhone by right clicking on your iPhone in iTunes and choosing 'Transfer Purchases'. You might need to Authorise your computer first by clicking the Store Menu, and then choosing Authorise This Computer.

For your non-iTunes Store content I'd recommend [Senuti](http://www.fadingred.com/senuti/) (read it backwards!) which lets you copy music from your iPhone or iPad back to your mac. Senuti costs $18, but there's a trial version, which can transfer up to 1000 songs.

Neither of these require a jailbreak.

Answer (score 8):

[Phoneview](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) - is a great option, as it allows you to access your entire media directory.  You can download a fully functional trial copy.

See this similar question: [Fastest way to transfer a bunch of photos TO iphone camera roll?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/fastest-way-to-transfer-a-bunch-of-photos-to-iphone-camera-roll/4644#4644)
[image]