# How can I transfer all my songs to iPhone instead of just purchased songs?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

When I connect and sync my iPhone to iTunes it only transfers over purchased songs and not songs I ripped from a music cd.  How do I get all of them to sync?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting my music from iphone to macbook](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4667/getting-my-music-from-iphone-to-macbook)

Comment: Hi Rich - Welcome to the site! It looks like another question here was worded a bit differently so I've asked for your question to be closed and merged with the other. Does this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to get around this issue, and I've detailed one below. Before trying that, though, see if this solves your problem:

1. Select the iPhone in the iTunes sidebar. Go to the Music tab and look at what music is syncing.
2. I expect maybe only the "Purchased" playlist is syncing, and that's why. If that's the case, simply select [image: Entire music library] and you're set!

Here's the other fix, if that doesn't work:

1. Select the iPhone in the iTunes sidebar. Find the tick box that looks like this: [image: Manually manage music and videos] and make sure it's checked.
2. Go to Music in the sidebar and select everything (Tip: <kbd>⌘ (command or control)</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>!).
3. Drag everything to your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Another small suggestion.  Select some song in iTunes that is not being transfered to the iPhone.  Look in the Advanced menu and see if the option "Create iPod or iPhone Version" is available.  If so, use it.

[image: MENU]